# Helper method for initializing child object for a given class in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, nested-forms

I have a nested form for has_many relationship using accepts_nested_attributes_for method. If I don't have a child object, then the nested form will not show up in parent's form. Therefore, I need to initialize child objects. One way to do this is:

```
# app/helpers/form_helper.rb
module FormHelper
  def setup_user(user)
   3.times { user.tasks.build }
   user
end
# app/views/users/_form.html.erb
<%= form_for(setup_user(user)) do |f| %>
  ...
```

How do I generalize this method to apply for other nested forms? Here is what I came up with, but it doesn't work

```
  def initialize_children(parent, children)
    parent.childrens ||= children.class.new
    1.times { parent.childrens.build }
    parent
  end
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, you should do this in controller.

But let's stick with your code:

```
def initialize_children(parent, children_sym)
  parent.send(children_sym).build # I don't understand your ||= purpose so I've removed it
  parent
end
```

Use it this way:

```
initialize_children(user, :tasks)
```